# Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg_1.18.25_armhf.deb

Tags: raspberry-pi3, magic-mirror

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-cairo python3-gi-cairo
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ca-certificates dpkg dpkg-dev file libcups2 libcupsimage2 libdpkg-perl
  libexiv2-14 libfaad2 libgs9 libgs9-common libmagic-mgc libmagic1
  libpam-systemd libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libsystemd0 libudev1 patch
  sense-emu-tools shared-mime-info systemd systemd-sysv tzdata udev
25 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,650 kB/19.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 471 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf dpkg armhf 1.18.25 [2,055 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf dpkg-dev all 1.18.25 [1,595 kB]
Fetched 3,650 kB in 11s (311 kB/s)
Reading changelogs... Done
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 116530 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dpkg_1.18.25_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking dpkg (1.18.25) over (1.18.24) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg_1.18.25_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 unable to stat './usr/share/man/de' (which I was about to install): Structure needs cleaning
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg_1.18.25_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Can you describe your issue in more detail, please?

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same problem.